# Uninstall program brainstorm

Tags: c#, windows

What I want to be able to accomplish is to silently uninstall any installed anti-virus software (I know it sounds like I will be making a virus but I'm not).

according to Microsoft guidelines every program that properly installs itself makes a registry entry in HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall. Usually, the key for the program will be its GUID, or else the name of the program. Within that key will be an entry called UninstallString so I just have to run that string in cmd I guess.

But I have never worked on anything like this before, since I am brainstorming if I will even attempt to do it find out how more experienced developers might approach it.

Comment: Agree with @ken2k This is much too open-ended a question, what have you considered? What have you tried thus far? Have you attempted to google your question as quite often answers can be found already.

Comment: I want to be able to silently open up everybody's bank accounts and transfer all the money to some other account. But my intentions are good! I swear!

Comment: I must've have worded the question wrong.. I was trying to accomplish this in order to install another anti-virus. It would be something like what appremover.com is doing now. Basically what I have do to now is to uninstall the anti virus software on my managed machines is write a script with the uninstall string. Which, like you mentioned as a result of security reasons, dont allow silent uninstalls. So it becomes a bit of an annoying process. But I was wondering if it was something that can be done, I am not trying to skirt around the security model as I will have administrator privileges...

Answer (score 5):

This is just not going to work out.

Regardless of how pure your motives may be (and I'll admit, I'm still rather suspect, despite your assurances), this is exactly the same thing that other people with impure motives would want to do.

Therefore, any antivirus vendor worth their salt is actively working to prevent this from being possible. In addition, as Matthew points out, Microsoft is working against you, too. In order to make this work, you'll have to figure out a way to skirt around the entire Windows security model.

I suppose you could enter an arms race against them, but they probably have a lot more resources to devote to the problem than you do and stand to gain a whole lot more from solving it. Moreover, the user is the one who stands to lose the most here. Not only is it extremely user-hostile to uninstall programs without their consent, if software vendors are spending their time locked in an arms race, they're not using that time, energy, and effort to improve their software in a meaningful way.

I strongly recommend abandoning the brainstorm before you've wasted too much time. Surely there's a better way to solve whatever task you're working on.

Comment: In addition to this, the program that is uninstalling the software would likely have to run with higher privilege, requiring user consent.

Comment: True enough. Not only are antivirus vendors working against you, so is Microsoft. You'd have to find a way to work around the Windows security model.

Comment: Whatever the barriers to this being done, there's simply no legitimate use-case in which removing any and all anti-virus software is going to exist, if they're having issues with false positives then the best thing to do is ensure correct signing from trusted providers or speak to the antivirus manufacturers, no?

Comment: well I was trying to accomplish this in order to install another anti-virus. It would be something like what appremover.com is doing now. 
Basically what I have do to now is to uninstall the anti virus software on my managed machines is write a script with the uninstall string. Which, like you mentioned as a result of security reasons, dont allow silent uninstalls. So it becomes a bit of an annoying process. But I was wondering if it was something that can be done, I am not trying to skirt around the security model as I will have administrator privileges...

Comment: Matthew that is fine, it is me that will be running it. But it will be removing it from all my managed machines, the purpose of the silent uninstall is to in order to avoid the user consent for the current users using the machine..